# UIView animation to move and back

Tags: objective-c

I would like to have animation on  a view, that it will go 2 pixels right on x, and 2 pixels back left on x .

I have this for opacity, and i am looking to adjust this to make it ,

```
    CABasicAnimation *theAnimation;

    theAnimation=[CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
    theAnimation.duration=1.0;
    theAnimation.repeatCount=HUGE_VALF;
    theAnimation.autoreverses=YES;
    theAnimation.fromValue=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
    theAnimation.toValue=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.3];
    [image.layer addAnimation:theAnimation forKey:@"animateOpacity"];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the animation to occur once then you can jump up a few levels of abstraction and use the block based view animations

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.f
                      delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse
                 animations:^{
                   view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(2.f, 0.f);
                 } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                   view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
                 }];
```

This applies a translation of two points right and then removes it on completion

Comment: You can learn a lot by reading the documentation.  For example, you can learn about `UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat`: “Repeat the animation indefinitely.”

Comment: thanks it worked with repeat .(but now i can't set another option to curve) .

Comment: You can you just separate the options with a logical OR (the pipe "|" character)